# Saving "this" when binding a function from a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple class in JavaScript:

```
function MyCounter() {
  this.counter = 0;
  $('#button').click(this.run);
}

MyCounter.prototype.run = function() {
  this.counter += 1;
  return console.log(this.counter);
};
```

This class is invoked like that:

```
var myCounter = new MyCounter();
```

HTML includes a single clickable button with ID="button". Clicking this button is supposed to increment an internal variable inside a `myCounter` instance. Obviously, it fails because `this.counter` does not exist, because at the time on execution of bound handler `this` equals to event, not `myCounter` instance.

A crude hack to overcome this is to save "this" to some other variable and wrap calling actual handler into a anonymous function:

```
function MyCounter() {
  this.counter = 0;
  var this2 = this;
  $('#button').click(function() {
    this2.run();
  });
}
```

Is there a better, cleaner way? Or at least, may be there's an universal agreement / style guide on how to name such "temporary this" variables?

Comment: Canonical names include `self` and `that`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.bind()`:

```
$('#button').click(this.run.bind(this));
```

---

`.bind()` creates a mini stub function that essentially does this for you:

```
var self = this;
$('#button').click(function() {
    return self.run();
});
```

Comment: Do I get it right that it's actually the same stuff (i.e. `bind` creates a new anonymous function anyway), but in slightly cleaner syntax?

Comment: @Kanpeki - Yep.  `.bind()` returns a new anonymous function that remembers the `this` value you pass it and then when called just calls your function with the right `this` value.

Comment: I hoped that it can be done without overhead of extra anonymous function, but if it's the official way to go - why not?

Comment: @Kanpeki - The extra function can't be avoided to solve this with `.click()` because `.click()` calls your function with `this` set to the DOM element that you registered for the event on.  That's just not what you want so you use a wrapper to give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really considered crude in javascript.
One common way of doing something like this would be:

```
function MyCounter() {
  this.counter = 0;

  var self = this;
  this.run = function() {
    self.counter += 1;
    console.log(self.counter);
  };

  $('#button').click(this.run);
}
```

Using the es6 syntax a common pattern would be to bind the function in the constructor:

```
class MyCounter {
  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.run = this.run.bind(this);

    $('#button').on('click', this.run);
  }

  run() {
    this.counter += 1;
    console.log(this.counter);
  }

  // And now you can also remove the event listener:
  destroy() {
    $('#button').off('click', this.run);
  }
}
```

But this pattern could also be applied to the old way of creating js classes:

```
function MyCounter() {
  this.counter = 0;
  this.run = this.run.bind(this);

  $('#button').on('click', this.run);
}

MyCounter.prototype.run = function() {
  this.counter += 1;
  console.log(this.counter);
}

// And again you can also remove the event listener:
MyCounter.prototype.destroy = function() {
  $('#button').off('click', this.run);
}
```

This is nice because you can now access the `run` method from the prototype before initiating the class.

But I think the bottom line here is that you can't bind something to the class instance before it has been created.

**Side note:** In all of my examples, the `run` method is bound to the class instance when it's initiated. This means that the `run` method does not need to be bound again i.e. `$('#button').click(this.run.bind(this));`.

#### Yet another pattern (a singleton, with private variables):

```
var myCounter = (function() {
  var counter = 0

  function run() {
    counter += 1
    console.log(counter)
  }

  $('#button').on('click', run)

  return {
    run: run,
    destroy: function() {
      $('#button').off('click', run)
    }
  }
})()
```

Since there is only one instance of `#button`, there is no reason to have the option of multiple class instances.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what it is, but I'm just not fond of the `bind` function. As an alternative, you can scope `this` to the object instance by wrapping it in an anonymous function, then use HTML 5's `onclick` property to bind the function to the template.

> [plunkr demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cjLaf9o0/4/)

```
var MyCounter = (function () {
    function MyCounter(counter) {
        this.counter = counter || 0;
    }
    MyCounter.prototype.run = function () {
        return alert(this.counter += 1);
    };
    return MyCounter;
}());


var counterInstance = new MyCounter(10);
window.counterInstance = counterInstance;

...

<button onclick="counterInstance.run()">Test</button>
```

Another strategy - a more OO approach - would be to pass the element reference to the class itself and assign the method in the class constructor. That would look something like:

```
class Counter {

    constructor(elementRef, counter = 0) {
        this.element = elementRef;
        this.counter = counter;

        //native HTML type
        this.element.onclick = () => this.run();

       //alternatively
       this.element.addEventListener('click', this.run);
    }

    function run() => { return this.counter++; }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the only thing your example does is to scope the class definition. You still need to use `bind` if you want to use event listeners. [See updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cjLaf9o0/2/)

Comment: Uhm, this is still all super weird... It's just convoluted. Also, `element.onclick` is bad practice. You should be using `addEventListener`, and don't get me started on the arrow function mess.

Comment: Guess I was too spoiled by frameworks. `Bind` is pretty essential to grabbing the right scope. My above answers are still valid, and it's hardly appropriate to call it 'bad practice' when OP's using JQuery to setup a 'class' with arbitrary id selectors that aren't even injected into the constructor. The whole situation is messy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `jquery` if you already have it in your stack. But setting the `onclick` function will prevent you from doing that again and would also overwrite a potential previous definition. It's best to do  `element.addEventListener('click', this.run)`. Also, the question isn't really about `jquery`

Comment: `onclick` has drawbacks, but they're hardly fatal. If you need multiple functions in an `onclick`, you can do that by wrapping your functions in a higher-level function. You can use `onclick` with `addEventListener` if you need to communicate outside your Controller. There's nothing wrong with `addEventListener`, agreed. I think you're being overly polemical about this though. There's nothing wrong with inline JS if you know what you're doing.  Finally, sure, JQuery is fine, but the *way it is being used* - id selectors(!) - is poor craftsmanship.